# Autocomplete flags after a subcommand

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

There is a program I have called `luarocks` that features a list of subcommands like `build`, `install`, and `make`, with flags after them. At the end, a command would like like the following:

```
# luarocks install varargs --server=https://example.com/`
$ luarocks make ./varargs.rockspec
$ luarocks pack ./varargs.rockspec
```

The zsh autocomplete command `_arguments` is able to take a list of flags like `-s` and `--long` and create descriptions for them, such as the following:

```
_arguments "-s[short flag]" "--long[long flag]"
```

However, this does not work well if a subcommand like `install` is included in the command, so when you type `luarocks install <tab>`, there is no list of flags. **How do I let `_argument` ignore any subcommands that are not included in the flag list?**

For reference, here is my current code:

```
#compdef luarocks

local curcontext="$curcontext" state line
typeset -A opt_args

local -a lr_commands
lr_commands=(
  build config doc
  download help install lint
  list make new_version pack
  path purge remove search
  show unpack upload write_rockspec
)

local -a generic_args
generic_args=(
  "--long[long]"
  "-s[short]"
)

_arguments \
  '1: :->cmd'\
  '*: :->args'

case $state in
  cmd)
    _arguments "1:Commands:($lr_commands)"
    ;;
  args)
    _arguments $generic_args
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @snowe2010 no, I've never figured it out.